# How to make a button do 2 things depending on a boolean value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Im trying to create a poll function on my site. I want the count to go up by 1 if the user has not already voted when they press the button and go down by 1 if the user has already voted when they press the button. Right now it justs goes up to infinity and never goes -1.

If I change the if(voted) to if(!voted) the opposite problem occures and just goes -1 by every click.

```
var voted = new Boolean(false);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#container div button").click(function () {
                if (voted) {
                    $(this).parent().animate({
                        width: '+=100px'
                    }, 500);

                    $(this).prev().html(parseInt($(this).prev().html()) + 1)
                    voted === true;

                } else {
                    $(this).parent().animate({
                        width: '-=100px'
                    }, 500);
                    $(this).prev().html(parseInt($(this).prev().html()) - 1)
                    voted === false;

                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: Maybe it is these lines `voted === true;` and `voted === false;`. They should use only `=` because it is the assign operator.

Comment: also `var voted = new Boolean(false)` has no purpose or merit, just do `var voted = false`

Answer (score 6):

`voted === true` should be `voted = true`

and

`voted === false` should be `voted = false`

you have to reassign the `voted` variable rather than check for equality.

Take a look at how the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) and the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) work in js

Answer (score 0):

`voted === true`
and `voted === false` are comparisons.

You should use `voted = true` and `voted = false` (which are proper assignments)